# java-script Regex filtering on words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following Regex:

The regex is in a bit of code in our app, I can see it splits words. It obviously removes characters such as $#* and so on. I need it to do the same thing exactly but allow the a hash tag, since the words can now have #hashtags.

```
"Test #words".toLowerCase().split(/\b/).filter(function(w){return w.match(/^\w+$/) }) // returns ["test", "words"]
```

The current Regex removes the hash, i want it to remain. So i get:

```
["test", "#words"]
```

Comment: Why don't you just `.split(/\s+/)`?

Comment: Would splitting on `\s` be sufficient?

Comment: The regex is in a bit of code in our app, I can see it splits words. It obviously removes characters such as $#* and so on. I need it to do the same thing but allow the hash, since the words can now have #hashtags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `"Test #words".toLowerCase().split(/\b/).filter(function(w){return w.match(/^\w+$/) })` does the following:

- The whole string is turned to lower case
- The string is split at any word boundary (leading and trailing, meaning `Test #words` is split into `[,Test, #,words,]`)
- The parts that match the `^\w+$` regex (1+ word chars from the start till end of string) are kept in the array.

You may use an identical *matching approach* to also include `#` with `/(?:\B#)?\w+/g`:

```js
console.log("Test #words".toLowerCase().match(/(?:\B#)?\w+/g))
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:\B#)?` - an optional `#` preceded with a non-word boundary
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars (from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` ranges)

If context is not so important, use a simpler `/#?\w+/g` regex that will match an optional `#` anywhere in the string, followed with 1+ word chars.

Comment: I' have added some more detail in the Questions. I want to make sure that the regex does exactly the same thing but allows/passes a hashtag in front of the word. Sorry if i was not completely clear.

Comment: That is impossible without code change. The reason is easy: JS regex does not support a lookbehind. Now, the question is: to what extent can the code be changed? I should say that my code above does exactly what you need: it extracts chunks of word chars optionally preceded with `#`.

Comment: Well I can change the regex. The approach you offer seems to work? I'm not a regex expert so I need to know what else does the regex you suggest other that allowing the # in-front of a word.

Comment: I tried to explain what your code does, and I think you now see I am doing the same thing, but now, `#` is also matched. Note that `/#?\w+/g` is context-unaware, and - from experience - I know that for the majority of people `\B#\w+` worked better. That is why I put the `(?:\B#)?\w+` version on top.

Comment: "Test #words".toLowerCase().match(/[\w#]+/g); This appears to do the trick!

Comment: No, `[\w#]+` will match `################` string.

Comment: If context is not so important, use a simpler /#?\w+/g regex that will match an optional # anywhere in the string, followed with 1+ word chars. this is the correct solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just add optional # at the beginning of the regexp to support #hashtags.

`"Test #words".toLowerCase().match(/#?\w+/g);`